# Maven surefire: append to argLine

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have 2 profiles that may or may not be used together to run a group of tests.  They each require different vmargs to run, but if they are used together it's ok to have them appended to each other.

What I'm looking for is a way to set argLine to be the concatenation of its current value plus what I set.

I was hoping it would as simple as

```
<argLine>${argLine} -DnewVMArg</argLine>
```

Is there something similar I can do to make this happen?

I made an attempt at fixing it which results in maven getting stuck in a recursive cycle. It's documented below.

My Most recent attempt was to define a property `<my.argLines></my.argLines>` globally, and then to modify this within the profiles.

In each profile, in a properties block, I set overrode the property to:

```
<my.argLines>${my.argLines} -myUniqueToProfileArgs</my.argLines>
```

In each surefire configuration for the profiles, I set `<argLines>` to be:

```
<argLines>${my.argLines}</argLines>
```

This logically fits for me, but the way it evalutes is apparently not going to mesh.

Comment: Is it working when you set the arguments explicitly, instead of using the global var?  Put your entire pom.xml file here, please.

Comment: Does it help to write as `<argLine>@{argLine} -DnewVMArg</argLine>`? This Hint is related to surefire / jacoco interplay, see https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/964

Answer (score 9):

Define your default arguments `-DnewVMArg` inside `argLine` like below:

```
<properties>
    <customArg/>
    <argLine>${customArg} -DnewVMArg</argLine>
</properties>
```

Define profiles arguments

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <properties>
            <customArg>-DmyUniqueToProfile1Args</customArg>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <properties>
            <customArg>-DmyUniqueToProfile2Args</customArg>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Additional plugin configuration is not required

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration/>
        </plugin>
....
```

I have tested this configuration, my results below.

Default

```
mvn surefire:test -X
```

Result

```
(...)java -jar -DnewVMArg (...)
```

Goal with profile

```
mvn surefire:test -X -Pprofile1
```

Result

```
(...)java -DmyUniqueToProfile1Args -DnewVMArg -jar (...)
```

Comment: That way, only profile1 OR profile2 could be actively contributing to the argLine, however in the original question, both profiles could be used together.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing only with -D system properties, you could use <systemPropertyVariables> instead of <argLine> and then they will be combined naturally. One of the profiles could have:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <propertyFromProfile1>value1</propertyFromProfile1>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

and the second profile:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <propertyFromProfile2>value2</propertyFromProfile2>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that this approach allows you to override in child poms individual properties from parent poms.

Comment: I think this not work for JVM options like `-Xmx1024m`, only for standard `-Dfoo=bar`, yes?

Comment: There's some language confusion here. I just said that your statement is correct. Also, I mentioned this detail in the beginning of my answer: "If you are dealing only with -D system properties ..."

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, a property cannot reference itself.

You need to define different properties for each profile and finally concatenate them in your surefire call:

```
<properties>
  <!-- it is a good idea not to use empty or blank properties -->
  <first.props>-Dprofile1Active=false</first.props>
  <second.props>-Dprofile2Active=false</second.props>
</properties>
...
    <!-- surefire configuration -->
    <argLine>${first.props} ${second.props}</argLine>    
...
<profile>
  <id>first</id>
  <properties>
    <first.props>-myUniqueToProfile1Args</first.props>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>second</id>
  <properties>
    <second.props>-myUniqueToProfile2Args</second.props>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Also note the not-empty default value. Maven has some surprising way of handling those. In order to be on the safe side, use harmless non-blank default values (see [“Null” versus “empty” arguments in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773134/null-versus-empty-arguments-in-maven))

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> TestNG -> Maven
Uncheck the 'argLine'.