# Using migrations with no sqlprefix

Tags: maven, flyway

Is it possible to have scripts with no sqlMigrationPrefix?  I just wanted to use numbers for my migration. Something along the lines of: 

 ../db/
   001__init.sql
   002__Add_foo_tables.sql
   003__Add_static_data.sql
   ...

I'm using maven and tried to use an empty tag...but that hasn't worked and I can't seem to locate anything on the docs for this.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a problem specific to the Maven plugin, or better said Maven itself. As Maven happily ignores empty configuration tags, one workaround might be to set the prefix to `0`, which would make it appear as though you have no prefix. But I agree, this is a workaround at best.

More info on the Maven issue: ["Null" versus "empty" arguments in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773134/null-versus-empty-arguments-in-maven)

Also you may be able to use a second workaround: start maven with `-Dflyway.sqlMigrationPrefix=`